# Merge battery and batteries tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Probably this should be a synonym; but I don't have the reputation to do so. I suggest battery as the remaining tag.

Comment: if you would like you can always come ask us in chat for things like this. Unless you see serious discussion chat can flag us and we can just take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Merged.

[image]
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Click!

Comment: I still think using the plural tag makes more sense. Reverse it!

Comment: @Kortuk - Yeah, that was my initial inclination as well.  I can't explain why, but it sounds better that way.